# Why does a single-threaded example of std::promise-std::future throw?

Tags: c++, multithreading

The following code throws `std::system_error` on recent g++, clang++ compilers and I do not know why. MSVC seems to work.

I was under the impression multi-threaded context is not necessary for `promise` and `future` to work.

```cpp
#include <future>
 
int main() {
    std::promise<int> p;
    std::future<int> f = p.get_future();
 
    p.set_value(1); //throws std::system_error
    return f.get();
}
```

[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/ErfYcfG88)

Stacktrace on my machine:

```
#0  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:50
#1  0x00007ffff7c38537 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:79
#2  0x00007ffff7e8c7ec in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#3  0x00007ffff7e97966 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#4  0x00007ffff7e979d1 in std::terminate() () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#5  0x00007ffff7e97c65 in __cxa_throw () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#6  0x00007ffff7e8f458 in std::__throw_system_error(int) () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#7  0x0000555555556fce in void std::call_once<void (std::__future_base::_State_baseV2::*)(std::function<std::unique_ptr<std::__future_base::_Result_base, std::__future_base::_Result_base::_Deleter> ()>*, bool*), std::__future_base::_State_baseV2*, std::function<std::unique_ptr<std::__future_base::_Result_base, std::__future_base::_Result_base::_Deleter> ()>*, bool*>(std::once_flag&, void (std::__future_base::_State_baseV2::*&&)(std::function<std::unique_ptr<std::__future_base::_Result_base, std::__future_base::_Result_base::_Deleter> ()>*, bool*), std::__future_base::_State_baseV2*&&, std::function<std::unique_ptr<std::__future_base::_Result_base, std::__future_base::_Result_base::_Deleter> ()>*&&, bool*&&) ()
#8  0x00005555555569ae in std::__future_base::_State_baseV2::_M_set_result(std::function<std::unique_ptr<std::__future_base::_Result_base, std::__future_base::_Result_base::_Deleter> ()>, bool) ()
#9  0x0000555555557417 in std::promise<int>::set_value(int&&) ()
#10 0x0000555555556346 in main ()
```

I fail to see how I am using `std::promise::set_value` incorrectly - `p` is valid and not set yet. Can anyone enlighten me please?

It works with `clang++ -stdlib=libc++` so the issue is somewhere in `libstdc++`, am I running into undefined behaviour or a bug?

Comment: Have you tried to catch the [`std::future_error`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future_error) exception thrown be [`set_value`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/promise/set_value) to see what the [error code](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future_errc) actually is?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes, it is "Uknown error -1", godbolt shows it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly, `std::future` depends on thread. So, you would need to link against `-pthread`.

Godbolt (with -pthread compiler option)
https://godbolt.org/z/hPTMKqMjr

Comment: Thanks that seems to work, do you know why exactly? I would expect linker errors, not exceptions at runtime.

Comment: @Quimby - Dynamic linking in the interest of backwards compatibility